# Setup remote connection to a dynamic IP PC on Windows 7

Tags: windows-7, connection, remote, dynamic-ip

I want to use the Remote connection in Windows 7. I'm trying to connect from my work PC to my home PC.

My home PC is connected to a router. I enabled port forwarding so that the remote connection port is accessible on my PC. Problem is that I can't know my home IP since it's dynamic and I would have to call home or something which is not practical at all.

How can I assign a dynamic DNS to my PC so instead of typing the IP I type the url? Is this possible? Both PCs use Windows 7.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is definitely possible to do this using a service like [dyndns](http://www.dyndns.com/support/clients/windows.html) - the link will take you to a windows client download but there is also the capability to update your dyndns on certain routers. You create an address such as yourhome.dyndns.com which is then updated every time your IP at home changes.

**However**, I am not a big fan of leaving RDP open to the world, the brute force attack possibilities make it a great candidate for investigation. I would strongly suggest that you either use some sort of [port knocking](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Port_knocking) or [port redirection over ssh](http://www.yak.net/fqa/81.html). Both of these are reasonably easy to setup if you were able to have a linux install somewhere but which should be possible on windows as well with some research.

Comment: Ha thanks - I knew I was missing something and that client is what it was. Thanks.